# How to define a custom generic type so pycharm would enforce it well

Tags: python, generics, pycharm, python-typing

In my project, we've adopted a return-value pattern, very similar to what you see in go.
Where we utilize being able to return multiple values to also convey expected errors, like so:

```py
def test_model(model):

    if something_wrong(model):
        return None, "somethings wrong"

    if something_else_wrong(model):
        return None, "somethings else wrong"

    return TestResult(), None
```

This works fine, but we're encountering some problems with pycharm's typing comprehension when I try and add type hinting.

What's required is this:

```py
def test_model(model) -> Union[Tuple[TestResult, None], Tuple[None, str]]
```

Which pycharm comprehends well:

[image: pycharm good typing comprehension]

So I was set to write a utility type to avoid writing long union typings since we're only interested in the types of the possible left or right outcomes.

And according to the [documentation on user defined generic types for the python typing library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types), I came up with this:

```py
EitherA = TypeVar("EitherA")
EitherB = TypeVar("EitherB")

Either = Union[Tuple[EitherA, None], Tuple[None, EitherB]]
```

But sadly, pycharm doesn't manage around this complexity:

[image: pycharm bad typing comprehension]

Am I constructing the `Either` type correctly?
Is there a way to have pycharm recognize it well, or write it differently so it will?

Answer (score 1):

Known bug, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29564 (thumbs up near the title)